# How works datetime and How to compare two dates in windows form ADO Entities?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, linq, datetime

I have table "Deposit" in my database sql server with column "DepositDate" and it's type is datetime.
I have rows with todays date and one of them is 2019-02-14 22:26:50.000 
And Today's date is the same , I mean 2019-02-14
But when try to get all todays row by following code, it doesn't work. I think it has something with those time that follow the date to do.
But write now I'am intreseted only day but I want to keed datetime type in my database.
So Must even time mutch with date I'am searching? I use Linq and Entities

I do like this , I do not get error but do not find the row. returning empty datagridview

```
DateTime TodayDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString());
 var deposit = (from u in db.Deposit
                                   where u.DepositDate == TodayDate
                                   select u).ToList();
                    if (deposit != null)
                    {
                        dgvDeposit.DataSource = null;
                        dgvDeposit.DataSource = deposit;
                    }
```

I tried even But I get erroe

> date is not supported in LINQ to ADO Entities

```
DateTime TodayDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.Date);
where u.DepositDate.Value.Date == TodayDate
```

I really appreciate your help

Comment: Use `DateTime.Today` to get today's date. `Now` includes the current time (`Today` is at 12:00am)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to filter between a start and end date if you want to make use of whatever indexes you might have on `DepositDate`. If you do not care about that there are [Canonical Date Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/date-and-time-canonical-functions) you can use to strip the time from the database value.

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);

var deposit = (from u in db.Deposit
               where u.DepositDate >= today && u.DepositDate < tomorrow
               select u).ToList();
```

Or as a lambda

```
var deposits = db.Deposit
                .Where(u => u.DepositDate >= today && u.DepositDate < tomorrow)
                .ToList();
```

---

As a side note and also a matter of opinion it generally recommended to pluralize `DbSet<T>` properties on your `DbContext` (like `db.Deposits`). The same goes for your variable `deposit` as it will be of type `List<Deposit>` which is a collection (the 2nd code sample I changed it).

Comment: @Igor Thank you It's working. Now I have learned something. I was wondering how to formulate it.